# Android app crashing: Not enough memory?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've developed an Android app, which gathers data from 2 txt files (I know a SQLLite database would be better), the files are 1,25 MB and 70 KB, so not that small and short (20000 Lines). So what I do is going through both of them via BufferedReader inside an AsyncTask, then creating a ListView to scroll through the lines. At first I just ran through one file, that took some seconds but was good, but then I ran through both files in one AsyncTask (consecutively) now I'm getting

```
The application may be doing too much in its main thread!
```

Altough its running on an AsyncTask... Then the app crashes with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

This is running on an Galaxy S4 with 2 GB RAM, shouldn't it be enough for 2 text files? Can I allocate more memory?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
ad = new Adapter(getActivity(), arrayParents);
ad.setAll(arrayParents);
mExpandableList.setAdapter(ad);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
search.setEnabled(true);
```

This is my onPostExecute(), the ListView is approx. 20000 lines. 'pb' is a ProgressBar and 'search' is an EditText.

```
    try {
        AssetManager am = MainActivity.am;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(am.open("manuf.txt")));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.startsWith("#") || !line.startsWith(" ")) {
                info.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(line.split("[\t#]"))));
            }
        }

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(am.open("pws.txt")));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                pwuser.add(line.split(";")[4] + ";" + line.split(";")[5]);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("FILE ERROR!");

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName(info.get(i).get(0));
        parent.setTry(info.get(i).get(1));
        parent.setTitle(info.get(i).get(0) + " - " + info.get(i).get(1));

        arrayChildren = new ArrayList<Children>();
        for (String s : pwuser) {
            arrayChildren.add(new Children(s.split(";")[0], s.split(";")[1]));
        }
        parent.setArrayChildren(arrayChildren);

        arrayParents.add(parent);
    }
```

This is how I read in the files, inside the doInBackground()

```
73586K/81016K, paused 475ms, total 475ms
12-13 22:59:59.253: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5938K, 9% free 75441K/82876K, paused 495ms, total 495ms
12-13 23:00:00.194: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5928K, 9% free 77292K/84732K, paused 538ms, total 538ms
12-13 23:00:01.125: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5912K, 9% free 79138K/86580K, paused 515ms, total 515ms
12-13 23:00:02.036: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5900K, 9% free 80981K/88428K, paused 502ms, total 502ms
12-13 23:00:02.826: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5888K, 9% free 82820K/90272K, paused 502ms, total 502ms
12-13 23:00:03.867: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5877K, 9% free 84656K/92112K, paused 539ms, total 539ms
12-13 23:00:04.738: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5861K, 8% free 86487K/93944K, paused 547ms, total 547ms
12-13 23:00:05.559: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5849K, 8% free 88313K/95776K, paused 534ms, total 534ms
12-13 23:00:06.450: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5838K, 8% free 90136K/97604K, paused 583ms, total 584ms
12-13 23:00:07.321: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5825K, 8% free 91956K/99428K, paused 582ms, total 582ms
12-13 23:00:08.192: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5810K, 8% free 93771K/101244K, paused 598ms, total 599ms
12-13 23:00:09.163: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5799K, 8% free 95582K/103060K, paused 640ms, total 640ms
12-13 23:00:10.104: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5786K, 8% free 97389K/104872K, paused 609ms, total 610ms
12-13 23:00:11.014: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5775K, 8% free 99193K/106680K, paused 629ms, total 629ms
12-13 23:00:11.985: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5763K, 7% free 100992K/108484K, paused 692ms, total 692ms
12-13 23:00:13.177: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5750K, 7% free 102789K/110284K, paused 735ms, total 735ms
12-13 23:00:13.187: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:14.318: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5739K, 7% free 104581K/112080K, paused 737ms, total 737ms
12-13 23:00:14.318: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:15.489: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5725K, 7% free 106369K/113872K, paused 769ms, total 769ms
12-13 23:00:15.489: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:16.670: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5714K, 7% free 108153K/115660K, paused 774ms, total 774ms
12-13 23:00:16.670: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:17.691: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5700K, 7% free 109934K/117444K, paused 740ms, total 740ms
12-13 23:00:17.691: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:18.902: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5689K, 7% free 111710K/119224K, paused 867ms, total 867ms
12-13 23:00:18.902: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:20.103: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5676K, 7% free 113482K/121000K, paused 854ms, total 854ms
12-13 23:00:20.103: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:21.304: D/dalvikvm(12888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5663K, 7% free 115251K/122772K, paused 833ms, total 833ms
12-13 23:00:21.304: I/Choreographer(12888): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:24.468: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 628K, 9% free 17871K/19600K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
12-13 23:00:24.478: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.213MB for 1774240-byte allocation
12-13 23:00:24.498: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 9% free 19600K/21336K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
12-13 23:00:24.518: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 19600K/21336K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
12-13 23:00:24.548: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.438MB for 15968032-byte allocation
12-13 23:00:24.568: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 35193K/36932K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
12-13 23:00:24.598: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 35193K/36932K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 29ms
12-13 23:00:24.638: D/AbsListView(14883): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-13 23:00:24.648: D/ProgressBar(14883): setProgress = 0
12-13 23:00:24.648: D/ProgressBar(14883): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
12-13 23:00:24.648: D/ProgressBar(14883): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
12-13 23:00:24.648: D/AbsListView(14883): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-13 23:00:24.648: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=0, getHeight()=0, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:24.658: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=0, getHeight()=0, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:24.668: D/libEGL(14883): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
12-13 23:00:24.668: D/libEGL(14883): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
12-13 23:00:24.668: D/libEGL(14883): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
12-13 23:00:24.668: I/Adreno200-EGL(14883): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3544079)
12-13 23:00:24.668: I/Adreno200-EGL(14883): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
12-13 23:00:24.668: I/Adreno200-EGL(14883): Local Branch: adreno_20130328
12-13 23:00:24.668: I/Adreno200-EGL(14883): Remote Branch: 
12-13 23:00:24.668: I/Adreno200-EGL(14883): Local Patches: 
12-13 23:00:24.668: I/Adreno200-EGL(14883): Reconstruct Branch: 
12-13 23:00:24.738: D/OpenGLRenderer(14883): Enabling debug mode 0
12-13 23:00:24.738: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=0, getHeight()=0, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:24.738: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=0, getHeight()=0, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:24.738: D/AbsListView(14883): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-13 23:00:24.738: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onLayout(), getWidth()=984, getHeight()=1392, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......ID 48,165-1032,1557 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:24.738: D/ProgressBar(14883): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-13 23:00:24.738: D/ProgressBar(14883): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-13 23:00:24.738: D/ProgressBar(14883): updateDrawableBounds: right = 228
12-13 23:00:24.738: D/ProgressBar(14883): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 228
12-13 23:00:25.118: D/AbsListView(14883): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-13 23:00:25.138: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=984, getHeight()=1392, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......ID 48,165-1032,1557 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:25.138: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=984, getHeight()=1392, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......ID 48,165-1032,1557 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:25.138: D/AbsListView(14883): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-13 23:00:25.138: I/endeffect(14883): AbsListView.onLayout(), getWidth()=984, getHeight()=1392, this=android.widget.ExpandableListView{421acc28 V.ED.VC. ......ID 48,165-1032,1557 #7f0b0006 app:id/expandable_list}
12-13 23:00:27.280: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4196K, 12% free 39191K/44484K, paused 3ms+35ms, total 100ms
12-13 23:00:27.280: D/dalvikvm(14883): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 68ms
12-13 23:00:29.583: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4396K, 12% free 41918K/47516K, paused 3ms+33ms, total 114ms
12-13 23:00:29.583: D/dalvikvm(14883): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 104ms
12-13 23:00:30.924: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7832K, 18% free 42046K/51152K, paused 121ms, total 122ms
12-13 23:00:31.615: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6556K, 16% free 43454K/51324K, paused 116ms, total 116ms
12-13 23:00:32.095: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6096K, 15% free 45340K/52744K, paused 122ms, total 122ms
12-13 23:00:32.545: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6099K, 14% free 47232K/54628K, paused 141ms, total 141ms
12-13 23:00:33.186: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6098K, 14% free 49126K/56520K, paused 165ms, total 165ms
12-13 23:00:33.837: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6096K, 13% free 51025K/58416K, paused 192ms, total 192ms
12-13 23:00:34.347: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6090K, 13% free 52922K/60316K, paused 200ms, total 200ms
12-13 23:00:34.978: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6079K, 12% free 54818K/62212K, paused 229ms, total 229ms
12-13 23:00:35.679: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6067K, 12% free 56712K/64108K, paused 274ms, total 274ms
12-13 23:00:36.459: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6056K, 12% free 58603K/66004K, paused 307ms, total 307ms
12-13 23:00:37.310: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6042K, 11% free 60490K/67892K, paused 312ms, total 312ms
12-13 23:00:37.921: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6025K, 11% free 62370K/69776K, paused 301ms, total 301ms
12-13 23:00:38.601: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6016K, 11% free 64249K/71660K, paused 343ms, total 343ms
12-13 23:00:39.302: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6004K, 11% free 66125K/73540K, paused 363ms, total 363ms
12-13 23:00:39.943: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5992K, 10% free 67996K/75416K, paused 348ms, total 348ms
12-13 23:00:40.623: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5976K, 10% free 69862K/77284K, paused 376ms, total 376ms
12-13 23:00:41.314: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5964K, 10% free 71725K/79152K, paused 374ms, total 374ms
12-13 23:00:42.155: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5952K, 10% free 73584K/81016K, paused 399ms, total 399ms
12-13 23:00:42.886: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5940K, 9% free 75439K/82876K, paused 426ms, total 426ms
12-13 23:00:43.616: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5925K, 9% free 77290K/84728K, paused 446ms, total 446ms
12-13 23:00:44.377: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5913K, 9% free 79137K/86580K, paused 463ms, total 463ms
12-13 23:00:45.428: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5901K, 9% free 80980K/88428K, paused 625ms, total 625ms
12-13 23:00:46.419: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5885K, 9% free 82818K/90268K, paused 484ms, total 484ms
12-13 23:00:47.340: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5875K, 9% free 84653K/92108K, paused 525ms, total 525ms
12-13 23:00:48.151: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5862K, 8% free 86484K/93944K, paused 526ms, total 526ms
12-13 23:00:49.002: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5847K, 8% free 88310K/95772K, paused 553ms, total 553ms
12-13 23:00:49.862: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5837K, 8% free 90133K/97600K, paused 566ms, total 566ms
12-13 23:00:50.753: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5825K, 8% free 91952K/99424K, paused 601ms, total 601ms
12-13 23:00:51.674: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5809K, 8% free 93766K/101240K, paused 605ms, total 605ms
12-13 23:00:52.575: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5798K, 8% free 95577K/103056K, paused 626ms, total 626ms
12-13 23:00:53.506: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5786K, 8% free 97385K/104868K, paused 636ms, total 636ms
12-13 23:00:54.447: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5775K, 8% free 99188K/106676K, paused 656ms, total 656ms
12-13 23:00:55.398: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5762K, 7% free 100988K/108480K, paused 663ms, total 663ms
12-13 23:00:56.419: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5747K, 7% free 102783K/110276K, paused 697ms, total 697ms
12-13 23:00:57.430: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5736K, 7% free 104574K/112072K, paused 722ms, total 722ms
12-13 23:00:58.571: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5722K, 7% free 106363K/113864K, paused 794ms, total 794ms
12-13 23:00:58.571: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:00:59.762: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5711K, 7% free 108146K/115652K, paused 763ms, total 763ms
12-13 23:00:59.762: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:00.853: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5700K, 7% free 109926K/117436K, paused 774ms, total 774ms
12-13 23:01:00.853: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:01.954: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5687K, 7% free 111702K/119216K, paused 790ms, total 791ms
12-13 23:01:01.954: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:03.115: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5675K, 7% free 113474K/120992K, paused 863ms, total 863ms
12-13 23:01:03.115: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:04.336: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5663K, 7% free 115242K/122764K, paused 885ms, total 885ms
12-13 23:01:04.336: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:05.628: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5650K, 7% free 117007K/124532K, paused 857ms, total 858ms
12-13 23:01:05.628: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:06.789: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5637K, 6% free 118767K/126296K, paused 858ms, total 858ms
12-13 23:01:06.799: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:08.040: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5625K, 6% free 120524K/128056K, paused 940ms, total 940ms
12-13 23:01:08.040: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:09.281: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Clamp target GC heap from 128.480MB to 128.000MB
12-13 23:01:09.291: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5612K, 6% free 122276K/129812K, paused 899ms, total 899ms
12-13 23:01:09.291: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:10.492: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Clamp target GC heap from 130.060MB to 128.000MB
12-13 23:01:10.492: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5176K, 6% free 123895K/131072K, paused 923ms, total 923ms
12-13 23:01:10.492: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:11.393: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Clamp target GC heap from 130.149MB to 128.000MB
12-13 23:01:11.393: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 298K, 6% free 123986K/131072K, paused 883ms, total 883ms
12-13 23:01:11.393: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6140-byte allocation
12-13 23:01:12.304: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Clamp target GC heap from 130.141MB to 128.000MB
12-13 23:01:12.304: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 6% free 123976K/131072K, paused 910ms, total 910ms
12-13 23:01:12.304: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:13.275: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Clamp target GC heap from 130.258MB to 128.000MB
12-13 23:01:13.275: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 393K, 6% free 124096K/131072K, paused 941ms, total 941ms
12-13 23:01:13.275: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6140-byte allocation
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Clamp target GC heap from 130.258MB to 128.000MB
12-13 23:01:14.376: D/dalvikvm(14883): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 6% free 124095K/131072K, paused 1102ms, total 1102ms
12-13 23:01:14.376: E/dalvikvm-heap(14883): Out of memory on a 6140-byte allocation.
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4220b980 self=0x6d20e510
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   | sysTid=14951 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1829392536
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4406 stm=104 core=0
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:~114)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at com.redox.defaultrouter.ListFragment.fill(ListFragment.java:135)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at com.redox.defaultrouter.ListFragment$PostTask.doInBackground(ListFragment.java:161)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at com.redox.defaultrouter.ListFragment$PostTask.doInBackground(ListFragment.java:1)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/dalvikvm(14883):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-13 23:01:14.376: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 23:01:14.386: W/dalvikvm(14883): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f60ac8)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:114)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at com.redox.defaultrouter.ListFragment.fill(ListFragment.java:135)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at com.redox.defaultrouter.ListFragment$PostTask.doInBackground(ListFragment.java:161)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at com.redox.defaultrouter.ListFragment$PostTask.doInBackground(ListFragment.java:1)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-13 23:01:14.386: E/AndroidRuntime(14883):    ... 4 more
12-13 23:01:24.236: I/Choreographer(14883): Skipped 587 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Please, post some code, unless you want us to read your mind!

Comment: what are you doing in your onPostExecute() method, can you show that, beacuse that happens on the Main UI thread !!

Comment: Can't really say much without seeing your code, but from what it sounds like I don't know if listview is what you need.  Probably something more like a single or couple of TextViews placed inside a scroll view

Comment: Sounds like @amitsingh is right. You're not doing your processing async.

Comment: Sorry I posted my code! (The file read in is inside the doInBackground())!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Also, I know you've said it yourself already, but you should still really use SQLite to parse your data into. If you use SQLite, your memory problems will all go away since your application won't need to keep everything in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you using API > 11 (Galaxy S4) you can give a try to the setting:

> android:largeHeap

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

but probably you have memory problem. Could you please also post the stacktrace for the out of memory?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help, the app is pushing itself to the limit, skipping 100 frames, extremely laggy, I will post the stacktrace

Comment: Update with Stacktrace

Comment: Could it be because I save my lines in an ArrayList?

Comment: try to use LinkedList instead ArrayList. The array list uses array to store the pointers and doubles its size every time reaches the max elements.

Comment: try LinkedList instead ArrayList with size.